# GDB Could not find the frame base in NetBeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, gdb

After making break point in NetBeans IDE, I am faced with problem which show the message `<error reading variable: Could not find the frame base for "nn::Layer::Layer(unsigned int, unsigned int)".>`. 
[screenshot](http://imgur.com/edit)
Because of it, I can't read values of variables even types of them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
I have tried several ways.

1. downgrade gdb from 7.9 to 7.7.
2. signing my gdb with `codesign -s gdb-cert /usr/local/bin/gdb` which did solve `Unable to find Mach task port for process-id` problem. But doesn't work for this issue.
3. Using lldb. However, using it even doesn't allow me to make a break point.

My MacOS version is `OS X EI capitan 10.11.1`. 
Gdb is `GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9`.
NetBeans is `8.0.2`.

If there is other version of gdb or NetBeans which works fine, tell me please.